# Write values in a ArrayList in a sequence after every 1 second to JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, arraylist

I'm trying to make countdown before the page redirected to another page like "You'll be redirected in (x) seconds. x is one of the String values those saved in a ArrayList. 
I tried this, but it waits end of the for loop  to write down seconds and result is like "54321".

```
 ArrayList<String> seconds=new ArrayList<String>();
 seconds.add(5); 
 seconds.add(4); 
 seconds.add(3); 
 seconds.add(2); 
 seconds.add(1); 
 <font size="45"><% for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
      out.write(seconds.get(i));
  }

 %></font>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a new thread and call this method from that thread, since otherwise it will be called only after the main thread is busy redirecting.

Thread example:

```
public class PrinterThread extends Thread {
  private Thread thread;

  private void method(){
    --add code here
  } 

  public void start() {
     if (thread == null) {
       thread = new Thread(this);
       thread.start();
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
     method();
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
PrinterThread thread = new PrinterThread();
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flush the response writer after every second, but this is a bad solution nowadays.

The best way to make a redirect after a countdown is to write a JavaScript to make it. Put the JavaScript in your html and let it control the countdown and the redirect.